# Change all childs id of a div element

Tags: javascript, html

Following my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="element">
      <div></div>
      <div id="c_a"></div>
      <div></div>
      <div id="c_b"></div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var element = document.getElementById("element");
var clone_element = element.cloneNode(true);
```

How to change the name of all the id (including the "element") of the variable `clone_element`?

Comment: well, the first step would be to try.

Comment: Hint: it involves `.id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the child divs of `div#element` using `clone_element.getElementsByTagName('div');` and loop through them, changing the `id` property of each as needed.

[Here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/domref/elementproperties.shtml) is a reference to some DOM object properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the id of the cloned element directly.

```
clone_element.id = "new_element_id";
```

The children can be accessed using the children property:

```
clone_element.children[1].id = "clone_a";
clone_element.children[3].id = "clone_b";
```